# Expected value of pair of success of

Tags: self-study, expected-value, hypergeometric-distribution

I am working on a problem from [Harvard Stat 110 problem set](http://projects.iq.harvard.edu/files/stat110/files/strategic_practice_and_homework_8.pdf). One of the problem (1.7.a) asks to find $$E\binom{X}{2}$$ , where random variable X is from hypergeometric distribution. What does the above expression means?

Also, in the solution of the second part of the question (1.7.b)  it states that

$$E\binom{X}{2} = E(X(X-1)) $$ . How to prove this ?

Comment: Is this the binomial coefficient$${x \choose 2}=x(x-1)/2$$ in which case the second equation is missing a division by 2...?

Comment: Oh...thanks Xi'an. I missed division by 2. It makes sense now.

Comment: And the $E$ would then be the expectation under the Hypergeometric distribution.

Comment: @Xian, Saurabh -- One of you two should write an answer so this doesn't end up unanswered.

Answer (score 1):

The problem asks to find $$E\binom{X}{2}$$. Random variable X is Hypergeometric. Expression can be interpreted as the expected number of pair of successes.

Expanding X choose 2 expression.

$$E\binom{X}{2} = E(X!/2!(X-2)!) = E(X(X-1))/2$$